How does whites bootstrap reality check work?
I am struggling to understand how it works regarding technical analysis and predicting a superior trading rule.

As it stands, this question is a bit sparse by our standards. Can you [edit] to include a bit more context please, explaining what the rule is and providing a citation where readers can learn more about it?

@Sycorax presumably Halbert White, A Reality Check for Data Snooping,  Econometrica, Vol. 68, No. 5 September, 2000 , 1097-1126 as mentioned in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25989/difference-between-whites-reality-check-and-monte-carlo-permutation

@Henry that could perhaps be the reference but it would nonetheless be helpful for OP to edit it into the question and remove all doubt & speculation!
